# secure store service customize user enter credential page

Tags: secure-store

It was pointed out to me that the `securestoresetcredentials.aspx` page under

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

gives a user the ability to enter credentials to a Secure Store Target Application.

In SharePoint what is the best practice with working with these layout pages? (Ex. I need to link the `securestoresetcredentials.aspx` page to a custom App Part after credentials are set.  This would be a 1 time entry if the user isn't part of the Secure Store Target Application they would be presented with this view as an intermediary step otherwise the will be shown the requested view).

I’m thinking that even if I can modify this page it might not be a good idea since it could be utilized for other Secure Store Service applications.  Maybe I need to create a custom page based out of this page?  If so how do you do this?

Comment: You talked about intermediary step. As part of the process instead of user why can't you add the current user to the respective group via SharePoint Server Side Object Model API's?

Comment: That would require me to lookup the SharePoint users credential of UserName and Password.  I see that there are ways to retrieve the UserName, but not the Password in SharePoint without using the Secure Store Service.  Do you have any suggestions about this?

Comment: You don't need the username and password. You can just get the User Token and Impersonate.

Comment: How do I get the user token?  I also am accessing the Power BI REST API which requires a token.  (I'm referring to the article, https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-a-web-app/  on "Step 5 – Use Azure AD access token to call a Power BI operation".  Would these both be the same token?  I get the Azure AD access token by using OAuth and passing UserName and Password information.  Thanks.